# New to ios protocols are supposed to force you to use methods, but it does not

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

My app compiles fine even though not all methods are used, here is my protocol:

```
@protocol azzams_customer_service_delegate <NSObject>


-(void)just_make_dice_appear_in_beginning;
-(void)generate_magic_numbers;
-(void)roll_the_dice;

 -(void)check_for_snake_eyes;
 -(void)Check_winning_number;
 -(void)flash_random_winning_number;
 -(void)update_winning_purse;
@required
-(void)u_need_to_im;

@end
```

I now attach this protocol to this class:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<azzams_customer_service_delegate>


-(void)just_make_dice_appear_in_beginning;
-(void)generate_magic_numbers;
-(void)roll_the_dice;

-(void)check_for_snake_eyes;
-(void)Check_winning_number;
-(void)flash_random_winning_number;
-(void)update_winning_purse;

@end
```

notice how  the following code is NOT implemented:

```
@required
-(void)u_need_to_im;
```

it should give an error, yet my app compiles just fine.

Comment: it probably gives you a warning?

Comment: When you conform to a protocol, the issue is not the presence of the declaration of the method in the `@interface` (as an aside, it's redundant to re-declare all of the protocol's methods in the `@interface`), but rather the existence of the method within the classes' `@implementation`. And even then, it's going to just generate compiler warning, and will only generate a runtime error if and when you actually try to call the missing method.

Comment: Do you have the method u_need_to_im in your implementation file? If yes, comment it and let me know what happens

Comment: what about the `@implementation`?

Answer (score 0):

The app will compile just fine, but you should see a warning saying that method is not implemented.

Comment: but the documentation states it will give an error, not just a warning

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, you will see a warning.  You can, however, turn on the option in the compiler "Treat Warnings as Errors". Of course, this means you will have to make sure your project is completely free of warnings.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is like - Say class A is the delegate of a protocol and it is supposed to implement a method XYZ. The program will work fine until another class/method tries to access XYZ. If it tries to access the required method, the program will crash.

Example : You implement UiTableViewSourceDelegate and you didn't implement the required methods. But you didn't use a tableview in your viewcontroller. You are on safer side.

Comment: i had another class which I attached this protocol to, and I did not implement a single method, still no error